# UIActivityIndicatorView randomly stops animating

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a `UIActivityIndicatorView` in a `UITableViewCell` that animates until the web view within the same cell finished loading it's URL request. What I've noticed is that the activity indicator always stops animating before the load is finished. I am not calling `[activityIndicator stopAnimating]` anywhere except for the webview `didFinishLoad` delegate method and having added a breakpoint there it does not fire and still the indicator stops animating randomly. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be much easier to get help if you provide some relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you hide the UIActivityIndicator and stop ? Try logic like this. Use NSURLSession and obviously the request will be asynchronous. So, before calling the request, make UITableView user interaction to NO and show acitivity indicator. After receiving or error, enable it back. Does it suit your problem ? Please do let me know, if you have any query. I'm using the acitivity indicator in the same way and it works perfectly.